# Unable to execute Commit Command

Tags: git

I am unable to execute the `commit` command. I tried commands like `reset` and squash and amend but nothing worked and I am just confused. I am a new user of git.

Here is a screenshot of what is happening:

[image]

Comment: Please tried `git add .` and after `git commit -m "My Initial commit"`

Comment: You need to `git add` the files you want to commit

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual commands and output as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because screenshots of console output aren't useful and OP missed the chance to copy/paste the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before to make a commit you need to add files to the stage area.
Use

```
git add .
```

To add all files in current directory and then try again with

```
git commit
```

If you need more details you could go to http://gitref.org/basic/

Comment: Thanks juan M. Hidalgo

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image, it seems that all the files are not tracked yet. Before git start tracking changes for a file, you need to tell git by running `git add <file>`. After which you should be able to run all your git commands.

Note that you wont be able to run some of the commands (like `git reset` & `git rebase`) until you commit (or trash) the changes first.